# Взять с списка кортежей первое число

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuple

У меня есть вот такой вот список кортежей:

```
<class 'list'>
[(49,), (51,)]
```

Собственно, как мне считывать эти элементы и переводить их в `int`

Comment: вы хотите перевести 2 числа в 1 число и сравнивать с другим таким же?

Comment: нет, извините, сейчас исправлю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list_ = [(49,), (51,)]

print(list_[0][0])
```

вывод:

> 49

если у вас в списке кортежы из одного числа то так можно превратить в списиок чисел

```
for i in range(len(list_)):
    list_[i] = list[i][0]
```

Comment: да, это отлично помогло, спасибо Вам!